# Is there a special names for associated prime ideals that neither contain nor are contained in other associated primes?

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology, definition

Let $M, P, Q$ be prime ideals in a commutative ring $R$ with $P$ properly contained in $M$ and $Q$ disjoint from both $M$ and $P.$ If $A$ is the $R$-module $R/M \oplus R/P \oplus R/Q,$ then the associated primes of $A$ are $M,P,Q.$ In ordinary terminology, $P$ and $Q$ would be called *isolated*, or *minimal* primes of $A$. Is there a particular term that I could use to indicate that $Q$ is not contained in another associated prime without writing out "$A$ has an isolated prime that is not properly contained in an associated prime of $A$?" It seems that *isolated* would be the perfect term, but that is precluded by standard usage. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say that such ideals are incomparable.

Comment: @user782932 - I appreciate the thought, and the obvious suggestiveness of "incomparable." However, I think I will use the term *separated*, since in the Hasse diagram for the poset $\mathrm{Ass}(M)$ such an element is, indeed, separated from the rest of the diagram.